# Error 500 Cognito 'token endpoint' /oauth2/token

Tags: oauth, amazon-cognito

I'm getting error 500 in token endpoint.
I'm using Google SSO with hosted login UI
he login URL is https:/sso.auth.ap-northeast-1.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=code&client_id=asd123&redirect_uri=https://dev.test.com:5000/dev.html

I'm using 'Authorization code grant' flow. After successful login it returns to url with authorization code callback_url?code=c015030f-d7bc-48e4-b046-0431b1b66ac7

Then I need to get access_token and refresh_token on 'token endpoint'.
url: https://sso.auth.ap-northeast-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token 
    using application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
    Authorization: Basic base64(client_id:client_secret)
fields

```
grant_type=authorization_code
scope=email openid profile
redirect_uri=https://dev.test.com:5000/dev.html
code=the code that I got to callback to url
```

I'm doing all as described in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html

All I get is error 500 and json 
    {"error": "Internal Error"}

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I had double space in header's Authorization between Basic and the hash. Anyway there is also a problem in error handling in amazon, we shouldn't get 500.